# Past and when should i use what?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

English grammar has been confusing me for a long time, so I want to ask some questions about the past and how you use it. I'm more interested in information about British English.

When and how do you use, for example:
haven't felt,
hadn't felt,
felt,
wasn't feeling,
has been feeling,
used to feel.

and what's the difference between them?

I kind of understand the difference, but not sure if I do it correctly.

Comment: A great place to visit could be [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad for this site. I think that a good pedagogical grammar book for English language learners is the best place to find answers about the contexts in which the various past tense forms are used.

Comment: The answer is very simple. We have a comprehensive chart over at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/300

Answer (score 0):

I haven't felt so happy for a long time (as I do now).

I hadn't felt so happy for a long time (as I did then).

I felt faint (at that moment).

I wasn't feeling very well (that day).

She has been feeling unwell lately.

I used to feel embarrassed when I had to read something out loud.